# Theory and step-by-step instruction of scipy.ndimage.convolve

Tags: python, scipy

Good day to all.

Help me please to understand theory of function scipy.ndimage.convolve for 1D arrays. I know the formula from http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html

```
 C_i = \sum_j{I_{i+j-k} W_j},
```

but i can't understand, how can I get results manually.

For example: `test_1 = scipy.ndimage.convolve([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`

result is `[24 24 30]`

Or `test_2 = scipy.ndimage.convolve([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5])`

result is `[15 22 31]`

---

If I write here all attempts that I have made, it will take a lot of space.

Give me please step by step instructions on what to do with these examples manually.

Answer (score 0):

Two tricky things going on here

1) the ndimage has this flag called "mode" which is set to "reflect" by default

2) two is that convolutions internally reverse one of the inputs

try comparing this piece of code

```
scipy.ndimage.convolve([1, 2, 3][::-1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],mode='constant')
```

to your by hand solution. (get rid of the "[::-1]" if you've already accounted for the reversal)